# Склонение имени сществительного

Tags: склонение, существительные

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с предложением:
Ваш труд заслуживает множество наград.
В каком падеже должно быть существительное "множество": "множества наград" или "множество наград"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: *Ваш труд заслуживает (чего) **множества наград.***

Вопрос № 254293. Как правильно: Заслуживает самою высокую оценку или
Заслуживает самой высокой оценки.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Правильно: **заслуживать чего, но заслужить что**: заслуживает самой **высокой оценки** (но: заслужил самую **высокую оценку**).

Вопрос № 215760. В тесте для российских чиновников был задан вопрос: "Проект заслуживает одобрение или одобрения". Как правильно?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Правильно: Проект заслуживает **одобрения**. Глагол "заслуживать" управляет **родительным падежом.**

[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)